# ESLint doesn't break build with Github Actions

Tags: javascript, github, continuous-integration, eslint, github-actions

I'm using **[Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions)** for the first time. I'm using **[Vue-CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/)** & I want to create a job that lint my files on `push` & breaks the build process if there's `ESLint'errors`.

This is my `package.json`'s scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
},
```

This is my `.github/workflows/main.yml` file:

```yaml
name: Lint files on push

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install modules
        run: npm install
      - name: Run ESLint
        run: npm run lint
```

I was using [this template](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-eslint) as inspiration. As you see in the screenshot below. The job is finished successfully, but it doesn't break the build or either fixes the linting. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify `--no-fix` so that it doesn't autofix errors/warnings and set `--max-warnings` to `0` as it seems you have one warning in your project and want it treated as an error.

In your `package.json`:

```json
{
  ....
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint --no-fix --max-warnings 0",
    ....
  }
}
```

[checkout documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/eslint.html#injected-commands)

Log output:

```
warning: Delete `⏎········` (prettier/prettier) at src/components/QuestionInfo.vue:5:25:
  3 |     <div class="question_card container">
  4 |       <BaseTag
> 5 |         :class="['tag', 
    |                         ^
  6 |         'p-5', 'pb-0', 'pl-0', 'ml-5']"
  7 |         :tag-name="this.tag"
  8 |       />


1 warning found.
1 warning potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
Eslint found too many warnings (maximum: 0).
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have found a way to lint the files & commit them. Do you think it's better to fix them on push or just show the error so the devs can address them? So basically what's best? your solution with just the errors or automatically fixing them like mine? I honestly don't know what's consider best practice here?

Comment: I guess warnings can automatically fix & errors will break the build anyway.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal if you commit and push in github actions, you will need to remember to pull everytime after the workflow has finished to run. It can lead to annoying merge if you forget to pull since any file may have been modified by your github action already while you're still working on the same branch (on the same files). I think it depends how you work, if that's only on a specific branch, who are working on it, if many people work on the same branch it may not be a good idea

Comment: It's really funny cause that's exactly what I just experienced! I guess it's better to not auto-fix the warning due to what you mentioned. For team collaboration, it could be confusing for new devs. I'll use your solution instead & if I want a warning auto-fix I can always use `githooks` for them . Tks! @Bertrand

Comment: @ManuelAbascal You're welcome. I've made a [covid19 New York scraper](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/covid19-nyc-vaccine-tracker) which scrapes a website and auto push the result on Github action to the same branch in a specific folder and I often forget myself to pull before pushing (although I'm the only one working on the project)

Comment: haha yeah it's better to not auto-fix in CI in general I think! I starred your project! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was linting the file, but I couldn't see the changes in my PR due that I wasn't committing & pushing the new changes.

I have refactored my `Github Action's workflow` to lint the files & push them to the repository.

```yaml
name: Lint files on push

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Installing node_modules
        run: npm install
      - name: Running ESLint
        run: npm run lint
      - name: Setting Github user.email
        run: git config --global user.email "<github-email-goes-here>"
      - name: Setting Github user.name
        run: git config --global user.name "<github-name-goes-here>"
      - name: Adding fixes for committing
        run: git add .
      - name: Committing ESLint fixes
        run: git commit -m "fixed ESLint issues"
      - name: Pushing fixes to current PR branch
        run: git push
```

You can get your `user.email` & `user.name` by typing in your terminal `git config --global user.email` &  `git config --global user.name` respectively.